# Why is background-position not fully sticking a background-image to the bottom edge of an element?

Tags: css, svg

I've the following issue: When I'm giving an element a background-image (an SVG) and I positioned with `background-position`, I get this tiny space between the image and the element at the bottom.

```css
body {
    color: black;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: cursive;
    background-color: tomato;
}
h1,h2,p {
    margin:0;
}
.bighead {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../img/park.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 100%;
}

.main-content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body class="bg">
    <header class="bighead">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="main-content">

    </main>
</body>
```

To solve this and make the image fully stick to the bottom, I've changed the vertical position's value to 100.5% so the SVG goes down overflowing the element. I'd like to avoid this and remain the whole SVG file without any gap between the image and the bottom edge of the `.bighead` element. Note that I'm using `background-color` on the body on purpose.

[image: background-position and a strange gap]

You note that tiny gap at the bottom, right? **Why is this happening?**

By the way, if you want the exact SVG file you could fetch it from: https://undraw.co/search, just search for `park` and It'll show up as the first image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you double-check that the SVG does not have an empty pixel at the bottom?

since when I use inspect mode on the page you linked, and select the SVG. Then zoom on the screenshot I take I also see this 1px.

[image: screenshot]